# How to display literal #{ @foo.bar } in input value?

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

Here is the code I have:

```
- snippets = ['state.name', 'city.name']
- snippets.each do |s|
    input type="text" value="#{ s }"
```

I need it to return( literally `#{ @foo.bar }` ):

```
<input type="text" value="#{ @state.name }" >
<input type="text" value="#{ @city.name }"  >
```

Everything I try returns a weird error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
input type="text" value=( '\#{ @%s }' % s )
```

`\#` and single quotes ensure the code inside wont be evaluated.

Comment: Either `\#` or single quotes; both aren't necessary.

Comment: @echristopherson are you sure? please reread the OP and post an working example

Comment: @slivu `input type="text" value=( '#{ @%s }' % s )` or `input type="text" value=( "\#{ @%s }" % s )`. I think it might have sounded like I meant you could leave off quotes entirely, but what I had in mind was either a) single quotes without `\` or b) double quotes with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
input type="text" value=#{ s }
```

Just FYI

```
<input type="text" value="<%= @state.name %>" >
```